# How can I force an OpenAI agent to wait after performing an action?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm creating a reinforcement learning model (DQN) for an old-school baseball Gameboy game. Focusing on offense first where the agent is at bat, the agent must choose between two simple actions – **A (Swing the bat) or None (Wait)**.

I'm having some issues with implementation; namely, the swing animation itself takes a long time; maybe around 80-90 frames or so. As such, if the agent decides to swing the bat, it will sometimes continue to try swinging the bat again (e.g. it chooses A over and over) *while* the bat is still swinging from the first A-press. I am currently doing something like the following to implement a frame skip:

```
# Main loop
for e in range(episodes):

    state = env.reset()
    ...

    while True:

        # Run agent
        action = agent.run(state=state)

        # 0 = SWING, 1 = WAIT

        # If we have a frame-skip, force the action to be WAIT and decrement
        if frame_skip != 0:
           action = 1
           frame_skip -= 1

        # If the action is a swing, set the frame skip
        if action = 0: 
           frame_skip = 90

        # Perform action
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action=action)

        ...
```

However, I'm worried that what I'm doing is shady and will probably mess up the model. In effect, the action that is being returned by `agent.run()`, which leverages the DQN model to either choose a random action or an action based on the policy, is being effectively ignored when the frame skip is happening.

Is there any way around this?